# Where do I find more info about such implicit class implementation

Tags: java, interface

I found some code like this

```
public class Test {
 static void myTest() {
    TestInterface test = new TestInterface() {

        @Override
        public void test1() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isOK() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    };
    if (test.isOK()) test.test1();
  }
}

interface TestInterface {
  void test1();
  boolean isOK();
}
```

This compiles well and probably would work, if it were more than a skeleton.
I understand it creates an implicit implementation of an interface and an instance of that class.
Trying to google this using "java" "implicit" "interface" does not give me more background info about this construct. Which is the search term I am missing ?

Comment: This is called an anonymous class : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Comment: Thanks @Berger Hope you love to answer easy questions ;)
   And thanks for the link as well.

Comment: @datafiddler you should probably mark Berger's answer as accepted then.

Comment: It's explicit, not implicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called an anonymous class : [Anonymous classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

As the expression implies, they don't have a name, and are used to declare AND instantiate a class that extends another class (or implements an interface), at the same time.

> Anonymous classes enable you to make your code more concise. They
>   enable you to declare and instantiate a class at the same time.

Those classes are local to the method that declares them.